# Рандом возвращает одно и то же число: как вернуть случайное число кратное 25, но не более 1000

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как сделать функцию, которая будет возвращать рандомное число, кратное 25 но не более 1000?

Я попробовал вот так:

```
return 25 * (rand() % 1000);
```

но вечно возвращается одно и то же число.

Comment: Поправьте код, сейчас он возвращает число от 0 до 24975 кратное 25.

Comment: интересное обсуждение с полезными ссылками: [Random number generation: It might be harder than you think to write code that rivals novice-level code written in Python.](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/31857s/random_number_generation_it_might_be_harder_than/?st=j8sghqd2&sh=32f94975)

Answer (score 4):

Раз у вас С++, гарантированное случайное число получается с помощью [`random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). Ну, а далее можно использовать самые разные распределения.

Я бы делал примерно так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 40);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int val = dis(gen)*25;

        cout << val << endl;
    }
}
```

В `val` получаются нужные вам случайные числа.

Comment: +1 за mt19937 (least-worst из стандартного для некриптографических нужд). Можно ещё инициализацию подправить: [Seed std::mt19937 from std::random_device](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/109260/6143)

Comment: ещё: [How to succinctly, portably, and thoroughly seed the mt19937 PRNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45069219/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй перед вызовом `rand()` вызвать `srand(time(NULL));` (потребуется заголовочный файл `<ctime>`).

Этот вызов сгенерирует случайное зерно для функции `rand();`.

Comment: В пределах одной секунды, тем не менее, будут одинаковые числа.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, верно, но это самый простой вариант решения проблемы.

Comment: Не перед вызовом, а в начале работы программы. Бывали уже тут ребята, которые массив заполняли связкой `srand-rand` и удивлялись, почему весь массив одним числом заполнен...

Comment: @Harry, вы имеете в виду вызов `srand-rand` в цикле? Конечно, я имел в виду не любые случаи, а лишь данный код.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << 25 * (rand() % 41);
}
```

подробности применения функции srand() можно прочитать здесь http://iguania.ru/article/random-number-generator

Comment: Для равномерного распределения можно что-то вроде `int((40.0 * rand()) / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * 25` использовать.